# Why does 本仕込 contain rendaku but 本絞り does not?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, linguistics, rendaku

Both words 本仕込 (ほんじこみ）and 本絞り（ほんしぼり contain the prefix ほん - the root words are しこみ and しぼり. They are morphologically similar nouns, so I am wondering whether this specific instance of rendaku is predictable based on the phonological environment of these words, or whether this is an aberration. I would have expected ほんじぼり (even though it sounds wrong to me).

Comment: It seems to be an instance where the following rule applies: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%80%A3%E6%BF%81#%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AE%E6%B3%95%E5%89%87_(Lyman's_Law)

Comment: [Are there any rules governing voicing in words formed via reduplication?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13059)

Comment: One exception that came to my mind is [ふんじばる](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%B5%E3%82%93%E7%B8%9B%E3%82%8B/) though this is not really a concatenation of two words.

Comment: Lyman's Law seems to apply to compound words, but I'm not sure a noun with a prefix qualifies as a compound. Compounds are usually noun+noun, adjective+noun, etc. At least according to this paper (https://www.atlantis-press.com/article/125983892.pdf), a compound is made up of elements that are free morphemes, which 本 as a prefix is not. Obviously 本 (book) is a free morpheme but that is not the meaning in this example.

Comment: @sundowner btw I also like I cats, languages, and whisky

Comment: The wikipedia link lists a word like 満足 as a rendaku example. I guess the notion of freeness could be different in Japanese than in Western languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rendaku usually doesn't happen when the second component already contains a voiced syllable. しぼり already has ぼ, and this is why it won't become じぼり. See: [Rules or criteria for 連濁: Voiced or unvoiced syllables in compound words](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2526/5010)

I feel 本絞り and 本仕込み are simple examples of "adjective + noun" fixed compounds like 長靴 (ながぐつ) or 大損 (おおぞん). This type of 本 means something like "true/ordinary/orthodox". At least in this context, I don't think it's important (or even possible) to strictly distinguish "adjective + noun" and "prefix + noun".

On the other hand, [本 meaning "our/this"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/59291/5010) can freely attach to many nouns (e.g., 本試み "our attempt", 本研究 "our research", 本サイト "this website"), and it never causes rendaku.

Comment: Great answer! Very informative